# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'String' and 'String' in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript trying to play with it. But I face a wired problem. When I try to concatenate two `String` type using `+` operator it's give an error that is

**Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'String' and 'String'**

My Code snap is

```
var firstName: String = 'Foo';
var lastName: String = 'Bar';
var name = firstName + lastName;
```

If I use `string` instead  `String` or add extra `''`it works fine. I checked, within JavaScript we can use `+` on two `String` object then why it's show error in TypeScript ? Is it bug or feature ? I definitely missing something. Detail explanation appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`String` is not the same as `string`. Always use `string` unless you really, really know what you're up to.

The upper-case name `String` refers to the boxed version of a primitive string. These should generally be avoided wherever possible -- they don't behave like normal `string`s in subtle and unexpected ways (for example `typeof new String('hello')` is `"object"`, not `"string"`).

Comment: And object probably does not work with + ;) (I do not know Typescript, just guessing)